# How do I root in python (other than square root)?

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to make a calculator in python, so when you type x (root) y it will give you the x root of y, e.g. 4 (root) 625 = 5.

I'm aware of how to do math.sqrt() but is there a way to do other roots?

Answer (score 7):

Use [pow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.pow):

```
import math

print(math.pow(8, 1/3))
```

**Output**

```
2.0
```

For your example in particular:

```
print(math.pow(625, 1/4))
```

**Output**

```
5.0
```

See more about exponentiation with rational exponents, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Rational_exponents). Note that in Python 2, as mentioned by @Jean-FrançoisFabre, you  need to specify the exponent to `1.0/n`.

Comment: python 2 needs `1.0/4` or you get 1 everytime

Answer (score 5):

If you want to 625^(1/4){which is the same as 4th root of 625}
then you type 625**(1/4)

`**` is the operator for exponents in python.

`print(625**(1/4))`

**Output:**

`5.0`

To generalize:

if you want to find the xth root of y, you do:

`y**(1/x)`